# How can I do this with Youtube videos on a site?

Tags: youtube, embed, shuffle, playlist

So how can I make it so when someone goes on my site it plays a youtube video and on refresh or if someone else goes on it, It plays a different video like a shuffle playlist?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not seen that in the api, but you can make a list of videos that you would prefer to have played and then have some code select one from the list at random.